# Запрос к бд - вбрать максимальную сумму

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть mysql таблица вида:

```
login | cena
--------------
user1 | 50
--------------
user1 | 50
--------------
user2 | 40
```

Нужно сложить все sum для каждого из логина и вывести из них сортировку по убыванию.

Должно получиться (из примера):

```
user1 100
user2 40
```

Имею код:

```
SELECT `table`.user AS user, SUM(`table`.cena) AS cena FROM `table` ORDER BY `table`.cena ASC;
```

Но он выводит общую сумму всех строк. Как ни крутил, ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT login, SUM(cena) AS sum_cena FROM `table` GROUP BY login ORDER BY cena ASC;
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!